# Relating factors of a polynomial over $GF(q)$ and $GF(q^m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials, galois-extensions

I am reading Richard Blahut's book "Algebraic Codes for Data Transmission" and have come to an impasse in my understanding in section 5.3.  In this section, the author wants to relate the factors of a polynomial over $GF(q)$ and the factors of that same polynomial over a GF-extension field $GF(q^m)$.

There is a good example in the book that I will use here to ask my question.  Specifically the $GF$ fields in this example use $q=2$ and $m=4$, so there is the prime field $GF(2)$ and the extension field $GF(2^4)$.  The polynomial to be factored over both of these fields is one with particularly special properties, of the form $x^{q^m-1}-1$.  So, the polynomial for this example is $x^{15}-1$.

The author first factors $x^{15}-1$ over $GF(2)$.  The prime factors are:
$$
x^{15}-1 = (x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)
$$
This factorization over $GF(2)$ makes sense to me and I can easily verify it in MATLAB.

The author then chooses two of the above prime factors and forms a new polynomial:
$$
g(x) = (x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)\\
= x^8+x^4+x^2+x+1
$$
The above multiplication over $GF(2)$ also makes sense to me and I can easily verify it in MATLAB.

However, the author then changes to analyzing the same polynomial $g(x)=x^8+x^4+x^2+x+1$ in the extension field $GF(2^4)$.  It seems to be implied that because $GF(2^4)$ in an extension field of $GF(2)$, and because the polynomial in question is comprised of prime factors (over $GF(2)$) of the special composite polynomial $x^{15}-1$, that this switch to the extension field $GF(2^4)$ is justified.

To analyze $g(x)$ in the extension field, we agree to represent the 16 elements of the extension field as the usual powers of the primitive field element alpha:
$$
0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, \alpha^4, \alpha^5, \alpha^6, \alpha^7, \alpha^8, \alpha^9, \alpha^{10}, \alpha^{11}, \alpha^{12}, \alpha^{13}, \alpha^{14}
$$

The author claims that the aforementioned polynomial $g(x) = x^8+x^4+x^2+x+1$ has roots/zeroes over $GF(2^4)$ at $g(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\alpha^3)=0$.

I am completely unable to make sense of this claim.  It raises numerous questions in my mind, and the most basic of these questions is, how can I verify that $g(\alpha)=0$ and that $g(\alpha^3)=0$?

To show how I've tried to verify that $g(\alpha)=0$ for $g(x)=x^8+x^4+x^2+x+1$, the author uses the following detailed representation of the elements of extension field $GF(2^4)$.  Of course to describe the elements of any GF extension field, we must choose an irreducible polynomial for the reducing modulus, and throughout the book the author uses the modulus $\alpha^4+\alpha+1$, yielding the 16 field elements:
$$
0=\alpha^{-\infty}\\
1=\alpha^0\\
\alpha^1=\alpha\\
\alpha^2=\alpha^2\\
\alpha^3=\alpha^3\\
\alpha^4=\alpha+1\\
\alpha^5=\alpha^2+\alpha\\
\alpha^6=\alpha^3+\alpha^2\\
\alpha^7=\alpha^3+\alpha+1\\
\alpha^8=\alpha^2+1\\
\alpha^9=\alpha^3+\alpha\\
\alpha^{10}=\alpha^2+\alpha+1\\
\alpha^{11}=\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha\\
\alpha^{12}=\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1\\
\alpha^{13}=\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1\\
\alpha^{14}=\alpha^3+1
$$
Given the above element representation of $GF(2^4)$, we return to the enigmatic claim that for $g(x)=x^8+x^4+x^2+x+1$, there is the root $g(\alpha)=0$ over $GF(2^4)$.  We have:
$$
g(\alpha)=\alpha^8+\alpha^4+\alpha^2+\alpha+1\\
= (\alpha^2+1) + (\alpha+1) + (\alpha^2) + (\alpha) + (1)\\
= (\alpha^2+\alpha^2) + (\alpha+\alpha) + (1+1+1)\\
= 1
$$
So it seems that for $g(x)=x^8+x^4+x^2+x+1$ polynomial, $g(\alpha)\neq0$.

Can anyone show me how to demonstrate that $\alpha$ (as a $GF(16)$ element) is a root of a polynomial that was computed over $GF(2)$?

If it would be helpful, I can scan the 3 pages of the book and you can see the author's own words for the above ideas.  He throws this information at you very quickly, so it's fairly difficult for me (as a non-mathematician) to follow.

Comment: Well, I may have keyed some information incorrectly, but I get $g(\alpha)=1$ (You counted the $\alpha$’s wrong.) But no matter, the result is not zero. It wouldn’t be the first time a book by a respected authority had mistakes in it.

Comment: Are you sure about $g(\alpha^3)\not=0$? No matter how you choose the generator of the multiplicative group its cube is a proper 5th root of unity and so satisfies $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$.

Comment: Are you sure the book intends to choose $\alpha$ as a root of the quartic you chose?  If you choose the reciprocal quartic everything the book asserts is true - it just seems to me mysterious why anyone would do this.

Comment: My somewhat educated guess is that, as @ancientmathematician also suspected, may be for Blahut $\alpha$ is a zero of the factor $x^4+x^3+1$? Can you check whether that is specified somewhere earlier in the book? I usually use the reciprocal $x^4+x+1$, just the way you did. The other primitive polynomial does have the benefit that it roots form a normal basis (but the roots of $x^4+x+1$ do not). That may (?) become relevant later on. Somewhat surprisingly I don't own a copy of Blahut, so I cannot check :-)

Comment: And @ancientmathematician got the other thing right also. Definitely $g(\alpha^3)=0$ because $\alpha^3$ is a root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ irrespective of whether the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $x^4+x+1$ or $x^4+x^3+1$.

Comment: For another way, you may have noticed that $x^8+x^4+x^2+x$ is the trace from $GF(16)$ to $GF(2)$. Therefore the zeros of $g(x)$ are exactly the elements of (absolute) trace  equal to $1$. That is, the elements of $GF(16)$ whose minimal polynomials have a non-zero cubic term.

Comment: I can show you how to find the minimal polynomial for $\beta\in GF(q^m)$ in case $\beta$ generates that field over $GF(q)$: It’s $(X-\beta)(X-\beta^q)(X-\beta^{q^2})\cdots(X-\beta^{q^{m-1}})$.

Comment: As everyone suspected, there is simply an error in the book.  The GF(2) factors the author meant to use are $x^4+x+1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.  The author mistakenly uses $x^4+x^3+1$ in place of $x^4+x+1$.  And yes, $g(\alpha^3)=0$ for the $g(x)$ octic polynomial, which was my error.  So a comedy of errors caused me to get stuck for 2 days!  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s really difficult to see what your author was trying to get at here. In this particular example, where the polynomial is $X^{15}-1$ over $k=GF(2)$, the way it factors over $K=GF(16)$ is that it splits completely into linear factors, ’cause the elements of $K$ are exactly the roots of $X^{16}-X$.

He has factored $X^{15}-1$ over $GF(2)$ correctly: the linear factors account for the elements of $GF(2)$, the quadratic factor accounts for the two additional elements of $GF(4)$, and the three quartic factors account for the twelve additional elements of $GF(16)$. You’ve used one of these quartics, the last one, $X^4+X+1=f(X)$, for constructing your $GF(16)$, and we have $0=f(\alpha)=f(\alpha^2)=f(\alpha^4)=f(\alpha^8)$, ’cause any time $\beta$ is a root of a $GF(2)$ polynomial $h(X)$, $\beta^2$ will also be a root of $h$.

His $g$ is product of the *other* two quartics you’ve written down, namely $X^4+X^3+1$ and $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$. It follows that every element of $K$ that’s neither in $GF(4)$ nor a root of $f$ will be a root of $g$. Since the elements of $GF(4)$ are $0$, $1$, $\alpha^5=\alpha+\alpha^2$, and $\alpha^{10}=1+\alpha+\alpha^2$, the roots of $g$ should be $\{\alpha^3,\alpha^6,\alpha^7,\alpha^9,\alpha^{11},\alpha^{12},\alpha^{13},\alpha^{14}\}$, of which there are fortunately eight.

I don’t know whether this will help your understanding, nor whether it will explain what your author was trying to convey. If you have questions, I can try to answer them in an addendum.

Comment: Indeed, $x^{15}-1$ is a very special polynomial over $GF(16)$, and in fact every non-zero element of $GF(16)$ is a root.  I will append to the question with more information about why $x^{15}-1$ was chosen.  And Indeed there are eight total roots of that particular 8th degree polynomial (of which I only listed two, $\alpha$ and $\alpha^3$).  The author claims the 8 roots are $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, $\alpha^3$, $\alpha^4$, $\alpha^6$, $\alpha^8$, $\alpha^9$, $\alpha^12$.  But I will append more info to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, if it’s that polynomial for $\alpha$ and that octic, the author is Wrong. I’m guessing,  @deltamind106 ,  that ancientmathematician has it right, that the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ should have been $X^4+X^3+1$.

Comment: I suspect you have the right answer here, because everything you say is in line with the book.  Can you show the GF arithmetic that demonstrates that $0=f(\alpha)=f(\alpha^2)=f(\alpha^4)=f(\alpha^8)$, for $f(x)=x^4+x+1$?  You say it's "because any time $\beta$ is a root of a $GF(2)$ polynomial $h(X)$, $\beta^2$ will also be a root of $h$.  But I don't follow that logic.

Comment: Never mind, it actually makes sense if you admit the author is wrong, and he incorrectly used the factor $x^4+x^3+1$.  The factor $x^4+x+1$ actually works.  So you correct, and the author just has an error in the book.

Comment: About the $\beta$-versus-$\beta^2$ thing, look at this: In characteristic-$p$, you have $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$. (Use Binomial expansion.) It follows that if $f(X)\in GF(p)[X]$, then $\bigl(f(X)\bigr)^p=f(X^p)$, because for the coefficients $c_i$, you have $c_i^p=c_i$ — they’re in $GF(p)$. In particular, if $f(\beta)=0$, you have $0=\bigl(f(\beta)\bigr)^p=f(\beta^p)$.